# MongoDB array with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, mongodb

I'm trying to insert data MondoDB with AngularJS's $http service , but one of the variables and the array What is in the collection , What to do ?

nome: string.
autor: string.
genero: array.
info: string.

**Collection: mangas.**

```
db.mangas.insert({nome: 'toriko', autor:'test', genero:['Ação','Aventura'], info:'...'})
```

**Server.Js, Find mangas.**

```
app.get('/mangas', function(req, res){
  console.log('i receive a get request')
  db.mangas.find(function (err, mangas){
    console.log(mangas);
    res.json(mangas);
  });

});
```

**Server.Js, Insert mangas.**

```
app.post('/mangas', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  db.mangas.insert(req.body, function(err, doc) {
    res.json(doc);
  });
});
```

*index.html*, **ng-click="addManga"**

```
<tr>
  <td><input class="form-control"manga.nome></td>
  <td><input class="form-control"manga.autor></td>
  <td><input class="form-control"manga.genero></td>
  <td><input class="form-control"manga.info></td>
  <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addManga()">Add manga</button></td> ----adiciona o metodo que se encontra no controller
</tr>

     <tr ng-repeat="manga in mangas">
       <td>{{manga.nome}}</td>
       <td>{{manga.autor}}</td>
       <td>{{manga.genero}}</td>
       <td>{{manga.info}}</td>
     </tr>
```

**Controller.js**

```
$http.get('/mangas').success(function(response) {
    console.log("eu recevi a data requisitada");
    $scope.mangas = response;
  });

  $scope.addManga = function() {
    console.log($scope.mangas);
    $http.post('/mangas', $scope.mangas).success(function(response) {
      console.log(response);

    })};
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is your problem?

Comment: sorry, i cant insert values ​​with $scope.addManga

Comment: On server.js , db.mangas.find, work, but no with  db.mangas.insert,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML:

you should use `ng-model` in html to bind with controller

Like:

```
<td><input class="form-control" ng-model="manga.nome"></td>
```

instead of

```
<td><input class="form-control"manga.nome></td>
```

and in controller:

you should use `$scope.manga` instead of `$scope.mangas` because of you bind `manga` in html input fields.

```
$scope.manga = {};
$scope.addManga = function() {
    console.log($scope.manga);
    $http.post('/mangas', $scope.manga).success(function(response) {
      console.log(response);

})};
```

Comment: Can I Take A doubt ? gender is array, the code sends string , how to improve it?

Comment: I want to create a manga reader , it would be Necessary to use mongoose to define the layout, to create a good website ? I have many doubts,

Comment: why gender is array? it should be string but multiple gender need to shown in UI not in DB . Not necessary to use mongoose but if you use mongoose then you can manage easily and  code will be readable and better for understanding.

Comment: I meant, gender, because it will have categories for example: action, adventure, so will facilitate the search by category, gender is genero in português.

Comment: well, one soln can be, add another button and function to push gender. like: `$scope.addGender = function(){ $scope.genders.push($scope.gender);};` and in `$scope.addManga` function assign those genders `$scope.manga.genders = $scope.genders`;